# how to run run synchronously two batch in spring batch?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have two batch. I need processes thousand of transaction using batch.I need to run both batches synchronous. One batch is started it won't get any request. If both batch completed then start again.

I am running these batch in Spring schedule.In my server there is two instance. For these reason, Both are running and make double transaction some times. That means , it create double insert in my database when running both instances.

**Here is my batch code:**

```
 public class RtgsJob {

        public Job createEft(){

            String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            id = "RTGS-STEP1-"+id;
            return new JobBuilder(id, jobRepository)
                    .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                    .start(step1())
                    .build();

        }


        public Job createEftTransaction(){
            String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            id = "RTGS-STEP2-"+id;
            return new JobBuilder(id, jobRepository)
                    .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                    .flow(step2())
                    .end()
                    .build();



        }

        private Step step1(){

            return new StepBuilder("step1", jobRepository)
                    .<mydata, mydata> chunk(10, transactionManager)
                    .reader(myReader)
                    .processor(myProcessor)
                    .writer(myWritter)
                    .build();
        }

        private Step step2(){

            return new StepBuilder("step2", jobRepository)
                    .<mydata, mydata> chunk(10, transactionManager)
                    .reader(myReader)
                    .processor(myProcessor)
                    .writer(myWritter)
                    .build();
        }

}
```

**I have run the code spring schedule. Here is the code:**

```
JobExecution execution = null;
    JobExecution executionTransaction = null;

    if(execution == null) {
        // rtgs batch step1 {} execution {} Started: 
        try {
            execution = jobLauncher.run(eftJob.createEft(), new JobParameters());

           // rtgs batch {} Step1 existStatus: "+execution.getExitStatus()

        } catch (JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException | JobRestartException | JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException |
                 JobParametersInvalidException ex) {
           
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            
        }



        if(execution.getExitStatus().getExitCode().equals("COMPLETED")){

            if(executionTransaction == null){
                log.info(Constants.batchTag + "{} rtgs batch step2 {} executionTransaction {} Started: ");

                try {
                    executionTransaction =   jobLauncher.run(eftJob.createEftTransaction(),new JobParameters());

                    //{} rtgs batch step2 {} executionTransaction {} Completed;

                } catch (JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException | JobRestartException | JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException |
                         JobParametersInvalidException ex) {

                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }catch (Exception ex) {

                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    

                }
            }
        }


    }else{
        //{} rtgs batch step1 {} execution {} isRunning: ;
    }
```

How to stop to insert double using spring batch?